# Include jar file in Scala interpreter

Tags: scala, jar, interpreter

Is it possible to include a jar file run running the Scala interpreter?

My code is working when I compile from scalac:

```
scalac script.scala -classpath *.jar
```

But I would like to be able to include a jar file when running the interpreter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to scala executable help all options of scalac are allowed ,
so you can run `scala -classpath some.jar`, i've just tried and it looks like it works

Answer (score 27):

In scala2.8,you can use

```
scala>:jar JarName.jar
```

to add a jar to the classpath.

In Scala 2.8.1, it is not :jar but :cp

And in Scala 2.11.7 it is not :cp but :re(quire)

Comment: I tried this and got a kind of success message.. but it did not work. Added '/shared/spark-core_2.10-0.9.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar'.  Your new classpath is:
".:/shared/spark-core_2.10-0.9.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar". But the import did not work. (NB: I verified the import works when adding via command line classpath)

Comment: Same with javadba: import doesn't work when a jar is added to classpath in interpreter, and you will have an error message *"object xxx is not a member of package yyy"* when doing that.

Answer (score 6):

Include multiple jars int Scala REPL 2.10.0-RC2

```
scala -classpath my_1st.jar:my_2nd.jar:my_3rd.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case i am using Scala code runner version 2.9.2. and i had to add quotation marks.
I am using this jar files:

jdom-b10.jar, rome-0.9.jar

and everything goes fine with this:

```
scala -classpath "*.jar" feedparser.scala
```

Answer (score 3):

In Scala version 2.11.6 from scala REPL use `:require`, can best be figured out by using `:help` from REPL

For example:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
scala> :require lift-json_2.11-3.0-M5-1.jar
Added '<path to lift json library>/lift-json/lift-json_2.11-3.0-M5-1.jar' to classpath.
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala version 2.11.5:

Here is an example of adding all jars in your ivy cache:

```
scala -cp /Users/dbysani/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10/jars/*

scala> import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
```

You can also create a local folder of all the jars that you need to get added and add it in a similar way.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"lib/*.jar" generates a list with blank between items not ":" or ";" as required.
Since Java 6 "lib/*" should work, but sometimes doesn't (classpath is set somewhere else)

I use a script like:

1. Windows:

   ```
   @rem all *.jars in lib subdirectory

   @echo off

   set clp=.

   for %%c in (lib\*.jar) do call :Setclasspath %%c

   echo The classpath is %clp% 

   scala -classpath %clp% script.scala

   exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%

   :Setclasspath
   set clp=%clp%;%~1
   exit /B 0
   ```
2. Linux:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   #all *.jars in lib subdirectory

   clp="."

   for file in lib/*
   do
     clp="$clp:$file"
   done

   echo $clp


   scala -classpath $clp script.scala
   ```