# Scala: Sbt can run project, but calling the jar results in ClassNotFoundError

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, uberjar

I have a project that will compile/package/run with SBT, but when I call the jar from the command line with Scala, I get a 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'.

build.sbt:

```
name := "coloring"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scala-graph" %% "graph-core" % "1.12.5")
```

running `sbt run` results in:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /path/to/dir/coloring/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[warn] there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Packaging /path/to/dir/coloring/target/scala-2.12/coloring_2.12-0.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Running Main 
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed May 21, 2018 12:55:19 PM
```

However running `scala target/scala-2.12/coloring_2.12-0.1.jar` results in

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scalax.collection.GraphBase$InnerNode
```

What could be going wrong here? How is it possible that `sbt run` works, but when you call the jar directly, it fails?

**EDIT**: I solved the problem using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), but (1) I don't think this should be necessary, and (2) in similar projects in the past, I have used the exact same build.sbt and library/imports/etc and the project works when called from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to assemble an uber-jar or similar, you'll need to have the dependencies on the classpath.

From the command line, that looks like:

```
scala -classpath my_1st.jar:my_2nd.jar:my_3rd.jar <whatever command>
```

So in your case, I imagine that looks like:

```
scala -classpath path/to/scala-graph.jar target/scala-2.12/coloring_2.12-0.1.jar
```

You can shorten `-classpath` to `-cp`

Here are quite a few other options: [Include jar file in Scala interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707454/include-jar-file-in-scala-interpreter)

Answer (score 1):

Libraries that you use need to be in the Java classpath. If you don't want to use assembly to include dependent libraries into a fat jar, you need to add them to the classpath some other way. For example via command line:

```
java -cp yourApp.jar:somelib.jar:someotherlibjar your.main.Class
java -cp yourApp.jar:libs/* your.main.Class
```